# How Override taxonomy term width multi vocabulary

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have 2 vocabulary. number: number1 number2 number3 width link taxomomy/term/1 => taxomomy/term/3 category: category1 category2 width link taxomomy/term/4 => taxomomy/term/5

I want create 2 view width body other. How to I can override taxomomy/term/% for vocabulary?

P/s: If I create path 2 view is taxomomy/term/%. => view 1 show result. view 2 show Page not found. I don't know?